# How fix my codeblocks compile programm use fstream, cannot open files large 20 mbs?

Tags: gcc, mingw, codeblocks, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     char fileInputPath[256] = "D:\25mb.file";
     ifstream fileInput(fileInputPath, ios::in|ios::binary);
     if (fileInput.is_open() != true) cout << "File not opened.\n";
     return 0;
}
```

programm result:
File not opened

tesing system win7 x32

Comment: Did you try `"D:/25mb.file"` or `"D:\\25mb.file"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open file with fopen, given absolute path on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466139/open-file-with-fopen-given-absolute-path-on-windows)